# Hibernate Envers: How to capture who deleted an entity in audit table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am using `hibernate-envers` with `spring`. Everything works just fine, except when I delete an entity, it does not change the values of `updated_by` and `updated_date` inside audit table, instead it saves an entity exactly as it was before (just copy) after `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete=true`.

I have already tried to register listener `EventType.PRE_DELETE`, but it didn't help.

Here is my UpdateEntity:

```
@LastModifiedBy
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long updatedBy;

@LastModifiedDate
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date updatedDate;
```

How can I capture who deleted and when was deleted inside audit table by modifying columns `updated_by` and `updated_date`?

Comment: @Andreas using `JpaRepository`

Comment: @Andreas delete method works as expected, copies all the values into audit table. But what I want is to modify values of `updated_by` and updated_date`

Comment: @Andreas that question is quite different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are combining to features: Auditing support and Envers.

Envers records every change to your entity including the delete if configured as you did.

Auditing support traces update and insert timestamps and users. 
It doesn't work for deletes since there would be nowhere to store that information.

If you want to keep the combination and still make it work you'd need to modify the entity (e.g. setting an extra flag `deleting` to true), flush it, maybe even commit it (I'm not sure if that is necessary) and then delete it.

Probably a better approach is using a custom revision object and store the required data there as described in this question and answer: [Ways to pass additional data to Custom RevisionEntity in Hibernate Envers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815460/ways-to-pass-additional-data-to-custom-revisionentity-in-hibernate-envers/37816083)

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing - *Combining Auditing and Envers*, which is wrong. I have done it by creating custom revision object. Thnx a lot

Comment: Auditing seems to be covered by Envers pretty fine if you use soft-deletion instead of hard deleting the records from the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom audit strategy:

```
public class CustomAuditStrategy extends DefaultAuditStrategy {

  @Override
  public void perform(final Session s, final String e, final AuditEntitiesConfiguration cfg, final Serializable id, final Object data, final Object revision) {
    if (data instanceof Map) {
      final Map dataToUpdate = (Map)data;
      if (dataToUpdate.get("REVTYPE").equals(RevisionType.DEL)) {
        dataToUpdate.put("modifiedBy", "test");
        dataToUpdate.put("modifiedDate", LocalDateTime.now());
      }
    }
    super.perform(s, e, cfg, id, data, revision);
  }
}
```

And then you should modify hibernate properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy: x.your.CustomAuditStrategy  
org.hibernate.envers.store_data_at_delete: true
```